# Azure DevOps - No hosted parallelism has been purchased or granted

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

As a new Azure DevOps learner I get this error whenever I try to implement a simple pipeline -

##[error]No hosted parallelism has been purchased or granted. To request a free parallelism grant, please fill out the following form https://aka.ms/azpipelines-parallelism-request

I'm using the default 'Azure Pipeline' Agent pool and am aware that if we fill the form we may get the grant. But I've been searching and reading solutions for it where I understand that thousands of people fill this form and the time it takes to get a grant can be too long or maybe never. And people suggest to setup our own PC or Azure VM as an agent, but then I would need to worry about keeping the right dependencies for the software used and also cannot experiment with different OS so easily.
So I'd really like to use the default Microsoft hosted agents first so I can focus on learning the tool.
Any help or suggestions would be appreciated :)

Tried creating a simple pipeline which wouldn't work with Microsoft hosted agent.
I expect the pipeline to work with default MS agent pool.

Comment: may i know if my reply answers? Let me know if you still have any queries.

Comment: Hi @wadezhou-MSFT, Thanks for your reply. I have submitted the form, but as many people said Microsoft may or may not revert back. But with the 'Buy Parallel Jobs' link I found that there is a free trial option also available. So I will take that for now. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to know it helps. It could take some time for the Microsoft to respond to your free agent request. As it's resolved, could you please help to [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) below according to How does accepting an answer work? This could help others which encounter same query. Thanks!

Comment: Sure! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the new DevOps organization, if you want to get the free Microsoft-hosted agent, you could have to submit the request here: https://aka.ms/azpipelines-parallelism-request.

[image]

Or you can set up billing to purchase the other jobs: [Buy parallel jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs?view=azure-devops&tabs=ms-hosted#buy-parallel-jobs)